# ngModel isn't updating when used inside a form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, 2-way-object-databinding

I am using Angular 10 and trying to bind elements of my login form to the view model, but it does not seem to be updating. It stays at the default initial value. What am I doing wrong?

login.component.html

```html
<div>
    <form #loginData="ngForm" (submit)="doLogin()">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="loginData.Username" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="loginData.Password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  loginData: any = {
    Username: "abcd",
    Password: "1234"
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  doLogin(): void {
    console.log(this.loginData); //prints { Username: "abcd", Password: "1234"} every time
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of your template variable for your form, it's conflicting with your `loginData` variable in your component.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kehnqw) showing it working.

Answer (score 0):

You have your default value as:
Username: "abcd",
Password: "1234"
This will always push those values. What you have to do is this:

```
loginData: any = {
    Username: "",
    Password: ""
}
```

Comment: Still isn't working. It just prints `{Username: "", Password: ""}` now.